# programatically getting SSRS hosted on Azure VM

Tags: azure, reporting-services

i am migrating my SSRS deployed on Azure SQL reporting to SSRS hosted on Azure VM. I have successfully created a VM and deployed my reports, which can be viewed from browser. now my requirement is that i want to get the reports in PDF or EXCEL format programatically. that requirment working fine for last one year but as i moved to VM when i called

ReportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters()

method it throw an exception 401 UnAuthorized access. i am currently using below class to get authenticate my user to get reports in PDF or EXCEl

```
public class SSRSReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials   
 {
         public SSRSReportServerCredentials()
        {
        }

        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            user = sa;
            password = test;
            authority = SERVER.reporting.windows.net;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Can any one help me out to fix my production issue.

best regards,
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys for too much late reply, i have fixed that issue almost 2 months ago but unable to find time to share my findings with you all. i have change the credential file as below and call the parametrize constructor

public class SSRSReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {
        public SSRSReportServerCredentials()
        {
        }
        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get { return new NetworkCredential(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]); }
        }

```
    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        user = null;
        password = null;
        authority = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```